# Find all Galois extensions of degree 6 of $K=\mathbb{C}(S,T,U)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $K=\mathbb{C}(S,T,U)$ be the rational function field over the complex field and $L$ be the splitting field of $F(x)=x^6-Sx^4+Tx^2-U\in K[X]$. Find $[L:K]$ and all the Galois extensions of degree $6$ of $K$ contained in $L$.

I have no idea. What should I do first?

Comment: Begin with this: if $\alpha$ is a root, then $- \alpha$ is another root. Now, call $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, -\alpha, -\beta, -\gamma$ the six roots. Note that $\alpha^2, \beta^2, \gamma^2 $ are the roots of $x^3-Sx^2+Tx-U$, which is the general polynomial of degree $3$ over $\Bbb{C}$.